# Deep link with react-navigation v5

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-navigation, deep-linking

I'm trying to use deep links in react native project with react navigation but I got some weirds scenarios in both platforms(ios & android).

My code
NavigationContainer

```js
const linking = {
        prefixes: ['https://latineo.com', 'latineo://'],
        config: {
            Home: {
                path: 'homestack',
                initialRouteName: 'Explore',
                screens: {
                    Explore: 'explore',
                    Posts: 'posts',
                    Favorites: 'favorites',
                    Settings: 'settings',
                },
            },
            ExploreOptions: {
                path: 'explorestack',
                initialRouteName: 'Restaurants',
                screens: {
                    Restaurants: 'rts',
                    ShowRestaurants: 'restaurants',
                    ShowRestaurant: 'restaurant/:id',
                },
            }
        },
    };

<NavigationContainer
            theme={navigatorTheme}
            ref={(nav: any) => {
                navigator = nav;
                NavigationService.setNavigator(navigator);
            }}

            linking={linking}
            fallback={<LoadingIndicator
                size='giant'
            ></LoadingIndicator>}
            onStateChange={(nav) => {
                console.log("AppNavigator -> nav", nav)
            }}
        >
            {isAuth && <HomeNavigator />}
            {!isAuth && didTryAutoLogin && didOnboard && didPermission && <AuthNavigator />}
            {!isAuth && didTryAutoLogin && !didOnboard && <OnboardScreen />}
            {!isAuth && didTryAutoLogin && didOnboard && !didPermission && <LocationPermissionScreen />}
            {!isAuth && !didTryAutoLogin && <IsAuthScreen />}
        </NavigationContainer>
```

HomeNavigator

```js
const Stack = createStackNavigator<HomeParamList>();
export const HomeNavigator = (): React.ReactElement => {
    return (
        <Stack.Navigator
            initialRouteName={'Home'}
            headerMode='none'
        >
            <Stack.Screen name='Home' component={HomeTabsNavigator} />
            <Stack.Screen name='ExploreOptions' component={LayoutsNavigator} />
            <Stack.Screen name='CreateOptions' component={PostNavigator} />
            <Stack.Screen name='FavoritesOptions' component={FavoritesNavigator} />
            <Stack.Screen name='SettingsOptions' component={SettingsNavigator} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
    );
};

export const HomeTabsNavigator = (): React.ReactElement => {
    return (
        <BottomTab.Navigator
            screenOptions={TabBarVisibleOnRootScreenOptions}
            initialRouteName={'Explore'}
            tabBar={props => <HomeBottom {...props} />}>
            <BottomTab.Screen name='Explore' component={LayoutsScreen} />
            <BottomTab.Screen name='Post' component={PostsScreen} />
            <BottomTab.Screen name='Favorites' component={LayoutsScreen} />
            <BottomTab.Screen name='Settings' component={SettingsContainer} />
        </BottomTab.Navigator>
    );
};
```

Scenario 1

When I try (App in background) with xcrun simctl openurl booted latineo://homestack/explore or latineo://homestack/settings, explorestack/restaurant/:id, etc it works fine, but when the app is closed(killed) it always open homestack/explore.

Scenario 2
When I try with explorestack/restaurant/:id it works but when I press a button that navigation.back() it back to a blank screen (If I use gestures from this white screen I can back to my home screen). [image: explorestack/restaurant/:id]

[image: blank screen]

Something similar happen when I try with explorestack/restaurants when I use back button it navigate to same screen but without header.

[image: explorestack/restaurants]
[image: without header]

Comment: any solution to this. i want to open user details screen, but it only open app. not navigating to user Details Screen

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, did you find any fix?

Comment: I did it from scratch with v6 and not facing the issue anymore